# V.8.5.6 Cannot enter german date

Tags: 2sxc

I've a problem with entering manually German Date in a Datefield. When i pick a date from datepicker, format is en-us.

In global settings i've enabled german culture, but nothing changed.

Is there anything else i must do?

Comment: Does nobody have any hints for me???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then typing a date in the DE format doesn't work. AFAIK this is an open issue on github https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/727

Comment: Thx for info. i didn't saw that.